# how to organize a selection box

Tags: html

I have a simple drop down box with a lot of ethnicities

```
<select name="ethnicity"  onchange="document.getElementById('actor').value='value1'" style=
              "width: 180px;">
                <option value="Whiteg">
                  german
                </option>

                <option value="italian">
                  italian
                </option>

               // + 100 more ethnicities
              </select>
```

I want to organize the drop down in a SINGLE drop down but i'd like to have bolded categories in between so instead of the drop down looking like

german 
italian 
mexican 
korean

it would look like

**White**
 german
italian 
 **Asian** 
 
 korean
 
 vietnamese

etc etcc

how would i accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="White">
    <option value="german">german</option>
    <option value="italian">italian</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Asian ">
    <option value="korean ">korean </option>
    <option value="vietnamese">vietnamese</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```